# React Context Provider all children re rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

can someone explain to me why the next code re renders all children components from the provider

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const ThemeContext = createContext();

const App = () => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(false);
    console.log("App running");
    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }} children={<Child1 />} />
    );
};

const Child1 = () => {
    console.log("Child1 running");
    return (
        <div className="child1">
            <Child2 />
        </div>
    );
};

const Child2 = () => {
    console.log("Child2 running");
    return (
        <div className="child2">
            <Child3 />
        </div>
    );
};

const Child3 = () => {
    const { theme, setTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
    console.log("Child3 running");
    return (
        <div className="child3">
            <p>{theme ? "dark" : "light"}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setTheme(!theme)}>Change theme</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

console everytime button is clicked, all components re rendering

```
App running
Child1 running
Child2 running
Child3 running
App running
Child1 running
Child2 running
Child3 running
```

but if context provider is wrapped in a component as follows

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const ThemeContext = createContext();

const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(false);
    console.log("ThemeProvider running");
    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }} children={children} />
    );
};

const App = () => {
    console.log("App running");
    return <ThemeProvider children={<Child1 />} />;
};

const Child1 = () => {
    console.log("Child1 running");
    return (
        <div className="child1">
            <Child2 />
        </div>
    );
};

const Child2 = () => {
    console.log("Child2 running");
    return (
        <div className="child2">
            <Child3 />
        </div>
    );
};

const Child3 = () => {
    const { theme, setTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
    console.log("Child3 running");
    return (
        <div className="child3">
            <p>{theme ? "dark" : "light"}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setTheme(!theme)}>Change theme</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

console when button is clicked

```
ThemeProvider running
Child3 running
ThemeProvider running
Child3 running
ThemeProvider running
Child3 running
```

only the component consuming the context (and the component context provider) are re rendering

how exactly react manages this situation

EDIT:

react version is 17.0.1 btw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because `<Context.Provider>` re-renders when its children prop **does not share reference equality** with the previous children prop.

In the first example, every time `App` is re-rendered, a **new** `Child1` React element is created.

It's basically like if you were doing something like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(false);
  console.log("App running");
  return React.createElement(ThemeContext.Provider, {
    value: {
      theme: theme,
      setTheme: setTheme
    },
    children: React.createElement(Child1, null) <= Notice how the children prop is new with every re-render
  });
};
```

which eventually re-renders `Child1`, `Child2` and `Child3`.

---

In the second example, the React element `Child1` is created once inside `App`, and it's passed down to `ThemeProvider`, which means that inside `ThemeProvider` you are actually referencing the **same** React element, and not creating a new one with every re-render, so in this case only the associated consumer component (`Child3`) will re-render.

```
const App = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(false);
  console.log("App running");
  return React.createElement(ThemeContext.Provider, {
    value: {
      theme: theme,
      setTheme: setTheme
    },
    children: children
  });
};
```

[Good read about why this happens](https://web.archive.org/web/20211120024251/https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/react-context-performance/)

Comment: The original function createElement makes it more clear than the syntactic sugar, at least for me

Comment: The front-end armory webpage you linked has some issue, the content disappears after one paint. Is it behind a paywall?

Comment: @sayandcode, yes, I can see that it's not working anymore.
I'll remove it from the answer

Comment: @HamzaElAoutar Actually that link was very helpful to understand the behaviour. I had suggested an edit which includes the link to the webpage, only through the Wayback Machine. Please consider including that

Answer (score 0):

In the first example the useState hook is being called in App which causes it to rebuild the children prop () as a new element that's being passed to the Provider, rebuilding subtree. In your second example, App is not being rerendered (as useState is moved down) so the children () prop passed to the Provider does not change and the subtree is not rebuilt.